# Firestore into different ViewController

Tags: ios

I'm building a student-tutor app using swift + firebase (auth and firestore).

I have a wrapper widget that checks if a user is logged in. If they're not, I direct them to an authentication screen (login/registration). If they are logged in, I then want to check if they are a student or a tutor.

In other words, in my wrapper, I need a way to retrieve user data from firestore and check their role and then direct them to the appropriate screen. I can't figure out how to do it. Please help. This is my wrapper class

```
let UID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("Users").document(UID!).getDocument { snapshot, error in
                                   if error == nil {
                             let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewControllerID")
                                 GetWindow()?.rootViewController = viewController
                                 GetWindow()?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                         }else{
                             
                             
                if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") {
                    GetWindow()?.rootViewController = viewController
                    GetWindow()?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("Users").document(UID!).getDocument { snapshot, error in
    if error != nil {
       for document in snapshot.documents {
          let UID = document.documentID
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the uid in different viewController via two ways.

i) Make a function and pass the uid, call the function in another viewController.

ii) let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid , by this term( You have to import the FireBaseAuth).

Comment: I changed it to this, it still doesn't work
 `
db.collection("Users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                         if uid == nil {
`

Comment: Actually, The snapshot contains all the documents in the collection("Users"). So, If you need to get a single document. Make use of the For loop, Then the document ID contains the uid. [  eg:  for document in snapshot.documents { let UID = document.documentID }. ]

Comment: I'm sorry.. but I still don't understand what you mean (maybe it's a translation problem), I beg you to give me an example code for me to learn, thank you very much

Comment: let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("Users").document(UID!).getDocument { snapshot, error in
if error != nil {
   for document in snapshot.documents {
      let UID = document.documentID
   }
}